# How to pass parameter to jquery UI dialog button function in extended feature?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to create popup window with jquery UI dialog, a parameter recordtype will decide the contents of the dialog to be load and the function to be called when pressing the button of the dialog.

```
function showPopup(div_id, w, h, title, recordtype, recordid) {

    $(div_id).dialog({
        height: h,
        width: w,
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: true

    });

    //----extend the ui feature-----
    $.extend($.ui.dialog.prototype, {
        'addbutton': function(buttonName, func) {
            var buttons = this.element.dialog('option', 'buttons');
            buttons[buttonName] = func;
            this.element.dialog('option', 'buttons', buttons);
        }
    });

    //----load content page------
    if (recordtype == 'research') {
        $(div_id).load('ResearchContents.aspx?ID=' + recordid);
        $(div_id).dialog('addbutton', 'Save', onclick);
        $(div_id).dialog('addbutton', 'Delete', onclick);
    }
    else if (recordtype == 'course') {
        $(div_id).load('CourseContents.aspx?ID=' + recordid);
        $(div_id).dialog('addbutton', 'Create', onclick);
        $(div_id).dialog('addbutton', 'Delete', onclick);
    }

}

//-----How to pass parameters to onClick? ----------
function onclick(recordtype, recordid) {
   if(recordtype=='research' && recordid==-1)
       createResearch();
   else if(recordtype=='research' && recordid>-1)
       updateResearch();
   else if(recordtype=='course' && recordid==-1)
       createCourse();
   else if(recordtype=='course' && recordid>-1)
       updateCourse();

}
```

My question is, how to pass parameters recordtype and recordid to function onClick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just pass the refence to the function as the callback, the only parameter you'll is the ony jquery passes when executing an event handler, which is an Event object.

Wrap the call to "onClick" into an anonymous function so you can call you method passing the parameters you want:

```
$(div_id)
    .dialog('addbutton', 'Save', function() {
        onclick(recordtype, recordid);
    });
```